# Css/ browser compatibility/joomla

Tags: css, browser, joomla

Sorry if this may have been answered before but I could really do with a specific answer to a specific set of circumstances.  I am very new to anything other than basic css.

The best way to describe what I mean would be to look at the site in various browsers. http://www.livingwithaddicts.com/
.

I have put this together for a charity using the Joomla CMS (version2.5).

If you look at the site in Firefox it is as (for now as it ain't finished) how it's meant to look.
It's fine in Chrome and passable apart from some easily solvable positioning issues in Opera.

Then we get to IE and I have just added **background:#485fc5;** to get it to render partly as i wanted and will do the same to get the bg on  the forms.

I would like to explore some other ways of styling so it looks acceptable in IE. I don't want to go down the route of replacing gradients or text shadowing with graphics.

Is there away of having a set of CSS that is only called if someone views in IE? If so how can I do this? Is this what's known as a hack?

Other possibilities are that as I am using Joomla, I have had to put some inline styling into specific content and I think some of the generated code might either be depracated and/or a bit messy. Would this affect how it renders.

Also I hurriedly (lazily) c& p'ed a chunk of css and modified the hex values to incorporate it in my existing css.(To anyone now sighing with disapproval, I apologize) This may not be the up to date syntax and I only heard of webkit the other day so that's what a novice I am.

I will paste it here and hopefully not embarrass myself to much. If anyone fancies a look (or a laugh) then please do. I would really appreciate any advice. Here is the the code.

```
body {
    background:  #485fc5;       
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom,  #485fc5 13%, #6e86ee 57%, #a0b0f5 79%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #485fc5 13%, #6e86ee 57%, #a0b0f5 79%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom,  #485fc5 13%,#6e86ee 57%, #a0b0f5 79%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,  #485fc5 13%,#6e86ee 57%, #a0b0f5 79%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom,  #485fc5 13%, #6e86ee 57%, #a0b0f5 79%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.13, #485fc5),
    color-stop(0.57, #6e86ee),
    color-stop(0.79, #a0b0f5));
}
```

Comment: Holy text wall. Can you reformat this to be a little easier to understand? Take out anecdotes and leave us with your specific question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a specific answer to your question, but it should help you on your way.

To target browsers that don't support specific features, use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). It won't let you target IE specifically, but it adds classes to the body tag that indicate whether certain properties are supported. You can then target those by using that class this way:

```
/* target browsers that don't support gradients */
.no-cssgradients {
   background-image: url(some-gradient-image);
}

/* a randomly chosen element on a page that doesn't support border radius */
.no-cssborderradius #some-element {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This way you can not only target IE but also other browsers that can't handle gradients, radius or dozens of other css properties.

Additionally, for simple gradients, border radius and box shadows you can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), which will enable you to use those features in IE (6 and up).

Comment: In addition, I can recommend some reset.css or normalize.css to make sure there's not native browser styles causing differences in the layout between browsers. I think some of the IE-specific errors are caused by those differences.

Comment: Thanks for that. So with the JS generated by modernizr. What do I with it? Do I put in a folder and call it from the head of the document.